# Not able to click on ionic specific tags in hybrid app using appium

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium, ui-automation, ionic2

I am trying to automate a hybrid app build in ionic2/cordova and typescript

HTML page somewhat looks like

```
<ion-input _ng_somename class="header-signin-part">
<input class="header" placeholder="heading" color="abc">
```

When I am trying to identify element using Xpath I am not able to

```
//ion-input//input[@class='header']

//input[@placeholder='heading']
```

I tried various other combinations but in vain. Can anybody tell me why am I struggling to identify elements. is it something in ionic which is stopping the element identification(ionic specific tags for not identifiable in webview)

> Steps whih I am doing
>
> 1. Launching the app using appium
> 2. Switching the context with driver.Context="WebView_1";(C# way of switching context)
> 3. Opening the safari browser and navigating to "localhost:27753" (Note: I have already started the webkit debug proxy on same port)
> 4. Identifying the elements

Also, app gets close everytime after some time without I doing anything. It doesn't hold on to webview

I am using only appium(not protractor) for automation

[image]

Comment: your xpath and html do not hold up. can you please reformat it?

Comment: @YuZhang added the screenshot of the content. please have a look.

Comment: which elements you want to click? <ion-input _ng_somename class="header-signin-part">
<input class="header" placeholder="heading" color="abc">

Comment: <ion-content class="scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header">
Above line was just to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways you can locate this element:

`<ion-content class="scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header">`

You can try:

- xpath: `//ion-content[@class='scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header']` (please bear in mind, it looks like there are **two space chars** between **ionic-scroll** and **has-header**)
- xpath: `//ion-view[@view-title='Home']/ion-content`
- css selector: `ion-content[class='scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header']`
- css selector: `ion-view[view-title='Home'][class='pane']>ion-content`